# Erro ao chamar função

Tags: python

Quando eu vou chamar esta função:

```
def check_bit4(input):
  mask = "0b010"
  desired = input & mask
  if desired > 0:
    return "on"
  else:
    return "off"
```

Aparece esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 9, in <module>
  File "python", line 3, in check_bit4
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'str'
```

Pesquisei, mas não achei uma solução para o erro

Comment: O enunciado pede para verificar o segundo bit menos significante? O que significa o 4 no nome da função `check_bit4`?

Comment: Pede o quarto bit, a posição do 1 da errada, eu troquei já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta tentando fazer uma operação bitwise com `inteiro` e com uma `string`? Isso não faz sentido, concorda?

Creio que o que você deseja seja algo como:

```
def check_bit4(input):
  mask = 0b010

  desired = input & mask

  if desired > 0:
    return "on"
  else:
    return "off"

print(check_bit4(0b1))    # off
print(check_bit4(0b1111)) # on
print(check_bit4(0b1010)) # on
```

Comment: No exercício do codecademy diz "Define a function, check_bit4, with one argument, input, an integer", na hora de testar eles estão passando um int

Comment: @lipesmile o `int` tá certo, o erro tá em usar a operação BITWISE `&` com uma string, **isso é string** `mask = "0b010"`, isso **não é** string `mask = 0b010`, entende? ---> https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lógica_binária

Comment: Ata, entendi, obg, funcionou aqui

Answer (score 0):

Já agora, uma sugestão: fazer funções um pouco mais genéricas.
Exemplo - uma função que dê o valor do bit `n` de um número: (Python3)

```
def bit(n,input):
   n=n-1
   return (input & 2**n) // 2**n

bit(1,3)   # 1
bit(2,3)   # 1
bit(3,3)   # 0
```